# android hide in EditText cursor

Tags: android

When the EditText is loaded, the cursor will be displayed the first EditText default. 
If I do not want to the cursor be displayed and move it to next EditText. How to realize this function?
This is the following code:

```
<LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="0px" />
```

Comment: I do not know why my question was voted down?

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the xml attribute `android:cursorVisible="false"` or the java function `setCursorVisible(false)` to hide EditText Cursor..

Comment: Ya，your method is right. I know one simply way is adding an invisible LinearLayout before EditText. But i do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the above code try this....

```
<EditText
     android:focusable="false"
     />
```